# problem sending an HTTPGET with PyCurl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl, http-get

I am having problems converting the following curl command into PyCurl:

`curl -k --cert /tmp/blablabla "https://blablabla"`

My attempt so far is shown below:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, submit_url)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPGET, 1)
b = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, cert)
c.setopt(pycurl.CAPATH,'/bla/bla/bla')
c.perform()
c.close()
```

This does not work. If anyone could tell me where I am going wrong that would be great!

Comment: Can you show us a traceback (if an exception is thrown) or describe the unexpected behavior?  Is it hanging forever, or what?

Comment: I have set pycurl to verbose and supposedly it was having problems finding my certificate. I have sorted this and the problem is now solved...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "--libcurl example.c" to your curl command line to get to see better what libcurl options curl uses, then you can copy them into your pycurl program rather swiftly.

Comment: Hi Daniel I don't have the  --libcurl argument with the curl set up I have. Will using --verbose gives me some useful information that may help.

Comment: Wow, then you have a mighty old curl version as --libcurl was added over 4 years ago. But no, --verbose won't really help you to figure out options. You don't seem to even try to do the -k action (ignore the server cert verification).

Finally: "this does not work" is not a very helpful way to describe what doesn't work. What exactly happens would be much better to know...

Comment: looks like the administrator has been taking it easy at work. I have set pycurl to verbose and supposedly it was having problems finding my certificate. I have sorted this and the problem is now solved...Thanks for your help