# Open URL using personal digital ceritificate with urllib2

Tags: python, https

I'm trying to use urllib2 to open a web page using personal digital certificate.

Actually by command line mode, using "curl -k", is possible to open this resource.

So my question is:

1) Is possible to open this web page using urllib2 bypassing the use of personal digital certificate?

2) If the option (1) is not possible, how can access this resource using urllib2 and "personal digital certificate".

P.S.
the code I'm trying to use in order to access this resource is the following:

```
class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def init(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.init(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert
```

```
def https_open(self, req):
    return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
    return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, key_file=self.key, cert_file=self.cert)
```

opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler('/Users/antonio/.globus/userkey.pem','/Users/antonio/.globus/usercert.pem') )
response = opener.open("https://........")
print response.read()

The error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HTTPSClientAuthHandler.py", line 18, in 
    response = opener.open("https://cmsweb.cern.ch/tier0/express_config")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 389, in open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 502, in http_response
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 427, in error
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Dude, it's urllib2 not urlib2 ;)

Comment: This looks like the http server is failing, somehow.  Do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: Actually I don't have access to server logs. By the way, using a web browser with a valid personal digital certificate, I can access it using Firefox 4.

Comment: As  Thouis said, there is a problem with http server and the code I'm using to access the server resource is right. By the way, it will be great to have this command "curl -k <url-resource>" converted into PyCurl. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved the problem.

I did access https service bypassing the use of personal digital certificate
simply in this way:

```
txdata = None
txheaders = {
    'Accept': 'text/html'
}
req = urllib2.Request(url, txdata, txheaders)
```

Any ideas why the headers 'Accept': 'text/html' allows connections to SSL sites without certs?

Maybe it depends by the server settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pycurl, but here are some links that might help:

[problem sending an HTTPGET with PyCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315070/problem-sending-an-httpget-with-pycurl)
(note in particular the suggestion to use --libcurl example.c to get the libcurl implementation)

http://code.google.com/p/friendlycurl/

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=270222.0

Answer (score 0):

What you have worked fine for me with one exception.  The init must have the double __ before and after since it is a special function that initializes the class.  This will always be the same function in every class:

class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def **_*init*_**(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.**_*init*_**(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert